# how to declare i and j to make it be an infinite loop?

Tags: java, infinite-loop

```
while( i <= j && i >= j && i != j) {}
```

how to declare i and j to make it be an infinite loop ?

// it's an interview question I met.

it's asking what's the declarations of i and j, make it be always true.

And I cant make it out by declaring i and j as number types. What other types can meet it ?

Comment: @DJClayworth what do you mean by "`||` version?"

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
Integer i=new Integer(1000);
Integer j=new Integer(1000);

System.out.println((i<=j)+" "+(i>=j)+" "+(i!=j));
```

`i` and `j` will be automatically unboxed to ints for `<=` and `>=`, but not for `!=`. `i` and `j` are different instances, but have the same int value. That's why all three comparisons will return true.

Comment: nice, I think it's the correct answer. At least it're returning true.// what a tricky interview question !!!

Comment: +1 `i <= j && i >= j && i != j` [evaluates to `true` in this case then](http://ideone.com/G1xjn)

Comment: +1 for accurate answer, but why would i and j not be unboxed for i!=j? Isn't i!=j supposed to check the values of i and j? Also what other languages this is true for?

Comment: @SpeedBirdNine It wouldn't be possible to do `i!=null` otherwise. Sometimes you want to compare instances instead of values.

Comment: @SpeedBirdNine More importantly i!=j was already valid code for Integer i and j, returning false for different objects. It is vitally important to Java that additions to the language do not change the behaviour of existing code.

Answer (score 3):

This works too ("on my machine"):

```
Integer a = 128, b = 128;
```

whereas this won't work:

```
Integer a = 127, b = 127;
```

Auto-boxing an `int` is syntactic sugar for a call to `Integer.valueOf(int)`. This function uses a cache for values from -128 to 127, inclusive. It *may* cache other values, but in my case, it doesn't.

Thus, the assignment of 128 doesn't have a cache hit; it creates a new `Integer` instance with each auto-boxing operation, and the reference comparison `a != b` is true. The assignment of 127 has a cache hit, and the resulting `Integer` objects are really the same instance from the cache. So, the reference comparison `a != b` is false.

What I really want to point out is to beware of reference comparison with auto-boxing. A more likely real-world problem is that you expect `a == b` is true because they were assigned the same (auto-boxed) value, you run some unit tests that confirm your expectation, and then your code fails "in the wild" when some counter exceeds the upper limit of the cache. Fun times!

Comment: +1 Great addition to [Banthar's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8015528/2932052)!

Answer (score -2):

Any equal value of 'i' and 'j' will reveal true with the given statement, say:

```
Integer i = new Integer(1);
Integer j = new Integer(1);

while( i <= j && i >= j && i != j) {}
```

The magic is with used operator! In case of != operator the compiler takes the operands as objects(including their values) whereas in case of >= or <= the compiler takes the operands value only. Thus, the above statement returns true.