# Tricky but not hard endless loop exercise

Tags: java, loops

I saw this exercise on a Java test, which finally led me to ask for ideas because there are some solutions I tried, but obviously won't solve the problem, due to Math conditions.

So the exercise:

> Define S and T variables as it results an endless while loop below!

```
while(s <= t && s >= t && s != t) 
{

}
```

Comment: Is the question asking how to make an endless loop by defining S and T?

Comment: Sure, it need to be an endless while loop.

Comment: Yes Johnny I guess so, thanks for linking it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

think about OOP, in fact 0!=0 is false, but new Integer(0) != new Integer(0) is true because it's not the same reference.
so `Integer S= new Integer(0); Integer T = new Integer(0);`
should resolve your problem

Comment: I was about the answer the question but Clain did it perfectly. You should refer to his answer.

Comment: Using `Integer.valueOf` with any value smaller -128 or bigger 127 should also work, as only number in between are part of the Integer cache and will reuse the same objects.

Answer (score 0):

here is answer :
This is not possible with primitive types. You can achieve it with boxed Integers:

Integer a = new Integer(1);
Integer b = new Integer(1);
The <= and >= comparisons will use the unboxed value 1, while the != will compare the references and will succeed since they are different objects.
you can check farther details in this link [How can "a <= b && b <= a && a != b" be true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042393/how-can-a-b-b-a-a-b-be-true/19042429)